# Pandas: failure to calculate correct quantile on large DF with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I seem to be unable to reproduce the 90% percentile of a distribution when using multi-column groupby on a large data set:

```
data.loc[(data.x=='2008Q1')&(data.y==-90)]['var'].quantile(0.9)
out: 1.030292
groupby_var = data.groupby(['x','y'])['var'].quantile(0.9).reset_index().rename(columns={'var':'u_var'})
groupby_var.loc[(groupby_var.x=='2008Q1')&(groupby_var.y==-90)]['u_var']
out: 0.187166
```

DataFrame data consists of 68M rows. x is string/object, y is float, var is float.
What am I doing wrong here? Result is way off.

**Update:**

Problem is related to missing values of y. Reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(0)
n=68*10**6
x_data = [str(i)+'Q'+str(j) for i in range(1950,2021) for j in range(1,5)]
y_data = [i for i in range(-90,91)]+[np.nan]
var_data = [random.randrange(0,10000)/10000 for i in range(n)]

data = pd.DataFrame(var_data,columns=['var'])
data['x'] = random.choices(x_data,k=n)
data['y'] = random.choices(y_data,k=n)
data['y'] = data['y'].astype(float)

data.loc[(data.x=='2008Q1')&(data.y==-90)]['var'].quantile(0.9)
out: 0.891
groupby_var = data.groupby(['x','y'])['var'].quantile(0.9).reset_index().rename(columns={'var':'u_var'})
groupby_var.loc[(groupby_var.x=='2008Q1')&(groupby_var.y==-90)]['u_var']
out: 0.8472

groupby_var_nan = data.loc[data['y'].notna()].groupby(['x','y'])['var'].quantile(0.9).reset_index().rename(columns={'var':'u_var'})
groupby_var_nan.loc[(groupby_var_nan.x=='2008Q1')&(groupby_var_nan.y==-90)]['u_var']
out: 0.891
```

**Question:** Why is the result of `groupby_var.loc[(groupby_var.x=='2008Q1')&(groupby_var.y==-90)]['u_var']` not the same as `data.loc[(data.x=='2008Q1')&(data.y==-90)]['var'].quantile(0.9)` and `groupby_var_nan.loc[(groupby_var_nan.x=='2008Q1')&(groupby_var_nan.y==-90)]['u_var']` ?

Is this expected behavior?
Isn't this a bug of some sort?